# Getting Python Pandas dropna method to work with 'N/A' values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file where some of the values in the fields are N/A. I have tried several methods in getting rid of those couldn't, nor could I understand how the `dropna()` function works.

Example:

```
name,   Age,    Status,
Ally,   21,     Single,
Daniel, 32,     Single,
John,   N/A,    Married,
Baker,  25,     Single,
Josh,   N/A,    Married
```

I am trying to use the dropna method to drop the 'N/A' value.
I want the result to return a list containing the age as `[21,32,25]`
How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Post your related code, and be sure to format your sample data as it is in your CSV file.

Answer (score 4):

Read the CSV file with [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) and specify `skipinitialspace=True`. This will enable the default "N/A" detection, which is prevented from working by the leading spaces.

```
>>> from pandas import read_csv
>>> df = read_csv('input.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
>>> df
     name  Age   Status  Unnamed: 3
0    Ally   21   Single         NaN
1  Daniel   32   Single         NaN
2    John  NaN  Married         NaN
3   Baker   25   Single         NaN
4    Josh  NaN  Married         NaN
```

The last column is empty, and is a consequence of the trailing `,` at the end of most lines. You can remove it:

```
>>> df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df
     name  Age   Status
0    Ally   21   Single
1  Daniel   32   Single
2    John  NaN  Married
3   Baker   25   Single
4    Josh  NaN  Married
```

Then you can remove the unwanted rows:

```
>>> df.dropna(inplace=1)
>>> df
     name  Age  Status
0    Ally   21  Single
1  Daniel   32  Single
3   Baker   25  Single
```

The final list is given by:

```
>>> ages = list(df['Age'])
>>> ages
[21.0, 32.0, 25.0]
>>> # or, if you want ints...
>>> ages = list(df['Age'].astype(int))
>>> ages
[21, 32, 25]
```

---

Here is the short version:

```
>>> df = read_csv('input.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
>>> ages = list(df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1).dropna()['Age'].astype(int))
>>> print ages
[21, 32, 25]
```

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean. Now, lets say that df = read_csv('input.csv', skipinitialspace=True) At the 'input.csv' part, I wanted to make like this, file = 'c:\somepath\input.csv' , then df = read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True) when I use this, it is not working. It says that the argument is suppose to be a string.

Comment: Try using a raw string for the file name: `filename = r'c:\somepath\input.csv' ; df = read_csv(filename, skipinitialspace=True)`. You'll probably find that this is the same, but using a raw string will avoid problems where you might form a special character due the the backslash, e.g. `\n`, `\t`, etc.

Comment: Ok.. thank you very much for your help. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If this has answered your question (I'm pretty sure that it has) then you should accept it.