# Issue with dropna() function and alternatives to the dropna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was learning to use the dropna() function in Python, in order to drop rows/columns which contained NaN/'?' values in them. However, even after seeing various solutions online, I couldn't drop data in spite of getting no syntactical errors.

I've tried the following solutions:

- [Pandas dropna() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712002/pandas-dropna-function-not-working) I tried this, but still, the data frame wasn't changed.
- [Python Pandas dropna method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217405/python-pandas-dropna-method) This method gave me a syntax error

First Attempt

```py
df1 = df.dropna()
df1
```

Continued

```py
df1.dropna(inplace=1)
df1
```

The first part of the code gave me the original data frame

The second part gave me the  following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df1.dropna(inplace=1)
>         2 
>         3 df1
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in dropna(self,
>   axis, how, thresh, subset, inplace)    4259         1  Batman 
>   Batmobile 1940-04-25    4260         """
>   -> 4261         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, 'inplace')    4262         if isinstance(axis, (tuple, list)):    4263             #
>   GH20987
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_validators.py in
>   validate_bool_kwarg(value, arg_name)
>       224         raise ValueError('For argument "{arg}" expected type bool, received '
>       225                          'type {typ}.'.format(arg=arg_name,
>   --> 226                                               typ=type(value).**name**))
>       227     return value
>       228
>
> ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type

Further, is there any better alternatives to dropna() function?

---

**EDIT 1**

1. Link to my Python notebook [Dealing with Missing Data.ipynb](https://github.com/pro-ady/data-science/blob/master/Dealing%20with%20Missing%20Data.ipynb)
2. I tried to change the argument value for inplace to True, but it gives me the following error:

> NameError: name 'df1' is not defined

PS
All the errors and issues are visible in the code

LINK TO THE CSV FILE USED = [CSV](https://github.com/pro-ady/data-science/blob/master/used%20automobiles.csv)

---

Comment: This means you don't really have `NaN` values, for the second error the error message is pretty clear, pass `inplace=True`, besides we need your data and code to reproduce this

Comment: The second error is readable enough - expected type bool means `True` or `False`, not 1 or 0. As to why your table does not change it is impossible to answer without a small example table. Likely what you think is "na" is not if I had to guess.

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can reproduce your error

Comment: i've added the code and the errors that i'm getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly replace ? with nan, like this:

```
df.replace('?', np.nan)
```

Then drop all the missing values using [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) (the nan's you just replaced above, like this:

```
df1 = df.dropna()
df1
```

and then use `inplace` to keep the DataFrame with valid entries in the same variable, like this:

```
df1.dropna(inplace=True)
df1
```

Comment: @user36160: That's great!  Don't forget to accept the solution if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `inplace = True` to the replace function

`df.replace("?", np.nan, inplace = True)`